# Работа с БД в AspNetCore

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

Изучаю aspnetcore, mvc и identity вместе с ними..
У меня есть БД (MSSQL создавать ее не нужно) со своей структурой, процедурами и тд.. Вопрос в том, что у меня нет понимания нужен ли мне для доступа к данным бд фрэймфорки типа Identity?

Я же по идее могу просто создавать пользователей с помощью тех же самых SQL процедур, а данные получать с помощью самописных методов типо GetUserByName, объявить свою модель User со своим набором свойств, а не то что предлагает IdentityUser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нужен ли мне для доступа к данным бд фрэймфорки типа Identity?

Identity предназначен для работы с учётными записями пользователей web приложения, а не управления доступом к БД. Это немного разные вещи. Если конечно у Вас учётные записи в web приложении не привязаны к MS SQL.

В целом же, точный ответ на этот вопрос зависит от задачи. Особенно, если говорить об управлении учётными записями.

С одной стороны, никто Вам не запрещает создать свою подсистему для этого. С другой стороны Identity уже содержит всё необходимое в готовом виде, включая решения относительно безопасности. В случае самописной реализации Вам придётся всё делать самому.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Поясните момент, у меня в БД есть пользователи и есть таблица Users куда при создании пользователя я складываю доп информацию(полей который нет в классе IdentityUser). Получается создавая пользователя через Identity я потом дополнительно делаю insert в свою табличку, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Как один из возможных вариантов. Можно и так.